# Directorio compartido entre Windows y Linux

Tags: redes, linux-mint

Uso la distro Linux Mint. El equipo está conectado a una red Windows, donde está el directorio a compartir. En Mint ejecuto la opción conectar con el servidor y se abre la ventana para introducir los parámetros. Simplemente introduzco el nombre en la opción servidor, en tipo selecciono "compartido por Windows", compartir y carpeta las dejo en blanco y relleno los tres últimos campos (nombre de dominio, usuario y contraseña).
Con esto consigo entrar en el servidor y tengo acceso al directorio compartido sin problemas.
La cuestión es la siguiente. ¿Cómo hacer que cuando arranco el ordenador aparezca la carpeta compartida sin necesidad de volver a repetir la operación, es decir que se guarden todos los parámetros y conecte automáticamente? Ahora mismo, en cuanto apago el equipo pierdo la carpeta compartida.
Gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En realidad lo que buscas es montar una unidad de red en linux de forma permanente, en el enlace que te dejo explican como montarla.

[Guia para montar unidad de red permanente en linux mint](https://ilovelinux.es/gnu-linux/unidad-de-red-en-ubuntu-linux-mint/)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Justo la respuesta que buscaba.

Comment: hahaha pero marcala como respuesta valida para que no quede en en pendiente, y me alegro que te sea de ayuda, ya que a mi me pasó lo mismo cuando migré a linux, cosas que eran sencillas en windows en 2 click, en linux se me hacian dificil

Comment: Solo puse la referencia porque son varios pasos y se volvería hacer un tutorial mejor dicho, pero en fin lo bueno es que se pueda solucionar el problema.